# Using a continuous distribution approximate the probability

Tags: probability, statistics

18% of all phones are undetectable. If 600 phones were manufactured, find the probability that

a) less than 107 are undetectable

b) no more than 107 are undetectable

c) exactly 107 are undetectable

I know that $p=.18$, $1-p=.82$, and $n=600$ I'm not sure what method to use

Comment: What is $p$ and $n$?

Comment: $p=.18$ The probability of a undetected phones and $n=600$ The amount of phones manufactured.

Comment: Binomial distribution for large value of $n$ and small value of $np$ can be approximated with a poisson distribution with $\lambda = np$.

Comment: You can also use normal distribution to approximate binomial distribution if $p$ is near $0.5$ and $n$ is large. In that case $\mu = np$ and $\sigma^2 = np(1-p)$.

Comment: The normal distribution is often used to approximate such binomial probabilities. It is a continuous distribution.

Comment: The normal distribution is often used to approximate such binomial probabilities. It is a continuous distribution. I have given you a start on that for part (a). If you make some progress on that and still have questions, please edit some more detail into your Question, and maybe one of us can help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have $U \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=600,p=.18),$ with $E(U) = np = 108.$
In the first part, you seek $P(U < 107) = P(U < 106.5) = P(U \le 106).$

From R statistical software the exact binomial answer is:

```
pbinom(106, 600, .18)
## 0.4410564
```

A normal approximation, using $U \stackrel{aprs}{\sim} \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = np, \sigma = \sqrt{np(1-p)}),$ can be found by standardizing and using printed normal
tables, or from software as below:

```
n = 600; p = .18;  mu = n*p; sg =sqrt(n*p*(1-p))
pnorm(106.5, mu, sg)
## 0.4366792
```

If you do this with printed normal tables, you may get a slightly different
answer because of the rounding involved in using tables.

A Comment by @expi suggests an approximation using the (discrete) Poisson
distribution. That might be convenient for the last part. For $P(X \le 106),$
the answer from software is.

```
ppois(106, 108)
## 0.4488446
```

---

All three answers are around 0.44 or 0.45. I suppose you are intended to
use standardization and printed normal tables. There should be an example
in your text on the procedure for that. Something like ...

$$P(U < 106.5) = P\left(\frac{U - \mu}{\sigma}<\frac{106.5 - \mu}{\sigma}\right) \approx P\left(Z \le \frac{106.5 - \mu}{\sigma}\right) = \cdots ,$$
where $\mu = 108,$ you can find $\sigma,$ and $Z$ is a standard normal random variable.